# Why curl of Dirac string attached to Dirac monopole is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-string

So let we have a magnetic field which is
$$B_\mu=\frac{q}{2}\frac{x_\mu}{|x|^3}-2\pi q\delta_{3\mu}\theta(x_3)\delta{(x_1)}\delta{(x_2)},\tag{4.65}$$
where $\theta$ is step function and $\delta{(x_\mu)}$ is dirac delta.

So in many places (for example Polyakov's book on gauges and strings at eq 4.64 and eq 4.65), it is said that for this magnetic field we have

$$\nabla\times\vec{B}=0 \tag{4.64}$$

but I can't see how, because the curl of the second term is not zero at least if I take the curl naively it will involve derivatives of Dirac delta and will be non-zero.

Comment: did you calculate the curl of the second term...? (recall derivatives of step functions are Dirac deltas)

Comment: yes since second term is only non zero at $\mu=3$ the curl involves derivatives of dirac delta

Comment: Why it should be zero if there is a magnetic charge there? It should be similar to the electric field curl, I guess. And magnetic filed has an odd parity.

Comment: its zero due to many books and papers, also ampere's law is not modified under magnetic monopoles.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, OP is right: The curl $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B}$ of the $\vec{B}$-field (4.65) is non-zero and violates Ampere's Law due to the presence of the [Dirac string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string). However, the Dirac string is a gauge artifact from using a globally defined [magnetic vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential) (MVP)
   $$\begin{align} \vec{A}~=~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+}\begin{pmatrix}y\cr -x\cr 0\end{pmatrix}\frac{q/2}{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon}(\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon}-z)}, \cr \vec{r}~\in~&\mathbb{R}^3.\end{align}\tag{1}$$
   The $\vec{A}$-field in eq. (1) and the corresponding magnetic field $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A}$ are [generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function)/[distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). For fixed regularization parameter $\epsilon>0$, they are globally defined smooth $C^{\infty}$-maps that satisfy $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=0$.
2. The presence of a [magnetic monopole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole)
   $$\begin{align} \vec{B}~=~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+}\frac{q/2}{(r^2+\epsilon)^{3/2}}\vec{r}, \cr 
   \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}~=~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+}\frac{3q/2}{(r^2+\epsilon)^{5/2}}~=~2\pi q ~\delta^3(\vec{r}),\cr
   \vec{r}~\in~&\mathbb{R}^3, \end{align}\tag{2}$$
   at the origin $\vec{r}=\vec{0}$ is an obstruction for the existence of a globally defined MVP. The best we can do is to cover the punctured 3-space $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{\vec{0}\}=\bigcup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}$ by locally defined MVPs $\vec{A}_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ in open neighborhoods $U_{\alpha}$ such that each pairs of MVPs in overlaps $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$ are connected by gauge transformations, cf. the [Wu-Yang bundle construction](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirac_monopole). This is e.g. worked out explicitly in Refs. 1 & 2.
3. The magnetic monopole (2) does satisfy Ampere's law $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B}=\vec{0}$ globally.

References:

1. M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics,* 1989; section 1.3.
2. M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics,* 2003; section 1.9.

Comment: i agree to your 2 and 3 but not 1. i think the $B$ in my question also satisfy amperes law. the trick is following: the curl of second term involves derivatives of dirac deltas. but dirac delta is meaningful only in integral and if we put it integral we can do by parts, and we will get zero contribution. so indeed curl of dirac monopole with string is zero.

Comment: there are several equivalent ways to describe magnetic monopole one of the ways is your wu-yang example. but the dirac string is also another way and it can not violate amperes law. and I think it does not, if we consider the derivative of Dirac delta carefully.

Comment: Concerning your above comment: One cannot hide a Dirac string under a volume integral sign. Test functions can in principle still detect and locate a Dirac string under a volume integral sign.

Comment: what I mean is, if you apply Ampere's Law in integral form $\oint\vec{B}\cdot d \vec{l}=0$ to the magnetic field given in eq. 4.65, you see that it is satisfied.

Comment: What if part of the closed integration contour is along the Dirac string?